# Finding the "Visible" tkinter Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Python's tkinter package. I've constructed a Notebook object, and assigned two frames that can be "tabbed" between...

```
notebook=ttk.Notebook(root)
frame1=ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2=ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame1,text="Tab 1")
notebook.add(frame2,text="Tab 2")
```

However, I can't figure out how to do one thing in this configuration. I want to write a function that can tell which "tab" the user is looking at. Perhaps it is called every five seconds, and it prints a "1" if the user is on tab 1 and a "2" if the user is on tab "2"? I'm hoping there is a simple function like frame1.isvisible() or something like that, but I haven't been able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Try `frame1.winfo_ismapped()`.  Also, `notebook.tab('current')` will give you info about the visible tab, but I don't think any of it would easily relate to the Python name for the tab.

Comment: Thank you for this, @jasonharper it is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the method notebook.select to find the tab currently selected.
But the problem is that it will not fetch you the direct result you want and rather will return you the tab_id

So you also have to use the notebook.index method to find the actual tab index and not the tab_id.

```
notebook.index(notebook.select())
```

This should answer you. But here too if you want the actual tab names you gave then filter it using the 'text' argument -:

```
notebook.tab(notebook.select(), 'text')
```

Another way to do it is using the current tag which saves the current tab value -:

```
notebook.index('current')
```

Both will give results as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems here:

1. How to find which tab is selected?

You should use the notebook's `.select()` method without any arguments. It returns the widget name of the currently selected pane.

2. How to observe the current tab selection?

To check which tab is selected you might bind to the `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` event and store the infromation about selected tab. This event is called every time the tab selection changes, so there's no need to poll every X seconds about the change.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

notebook=ttk.Notebook(root)
frame1=tk.Frame(notebook)
frame2=tk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame1,text="Tab 1")
notebook.add(frame2,text="Tab 2")

def print_tab_num(nb, event):
    print(f"Selected {nb.select()} tab which has index: {nb.index(nb.select())}")

notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", lambda evt: print_tab_num(notebook, evt))

notebook.pack()
root.mainloop()
```